# Python Chartify Library: chromedriver permission issues

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, chartify

I am trying to use the Python library **Chartify** (Py3) though when I try to show my graph as 'png' I get an error.

```
# Generate example data
data = chartify.examples.example_data()    

# Plot the data
ch = chartify.Chart(blank_labels=True, x_axis_type='datetime')
ch.plot.scatter(data_frame=data,x_column='date',y_column='unit_price')
ch.set_title("Scatterplot")
ch.set_subtitle("Plot two numeric values.")
ch.show('png')
```

The error is the following:

> WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong
>   permissions. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I already downloaded chromedriver and placed it in my path. I verified that is in my path using `os.path.exists`. My Chrome browser is up to date (Mac). When I run the following code, I get the same error as above.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(my_path + '/chromedriver')
```

What am I missing? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `'my_path'` as a string rather than the variable `my_path`

I recommend passing the path as an argument of `executable_path`

Here's the correct code.

`from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=(my_path + '/chromedriver)')`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my end. It is the actual path that I'm referencing from another file that has os.getcwd()